# Select crossed data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table as follow :

```
id      int(20)
ip      varchar(25)
temp    float
batt    int(4)
date    datetime
```

This table is fed from sensors gathering data and filling the table every 15 seconds.

```
1   fe80::212:4b00:60d:b27f 17.62   3256    2017-03-20 01:58:31
2   fe80::212:4b00:60d:6215 19.524  3264    2017-03-20 01:58:43
3   fe80::212:4b00:60d:b27f 17.62   3256    2017-03-20 01:58:46
4   fe80::212:4b00:60d:6215 19.524  3263    2017-03-20 01:58:58
5   fe80::212:4b00:60d:b27f 17.62   3256    2017-03-20 01:59:01
```

I wish to get the average temperature (`temp`) by sensor (`ip`) and by hour (`date`)

Something like the following output :

```
           IP              00:00   01:00   02:00   ... 
fe80::212:4b00:60d:b27f    18.16   18.20   18.23   ...
fe80::212:4b00:60d:6215    19.54   20.12   20.30   ...
```

Any idea about how to get crossed-data output in mysql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do use conditional aggregation:

```
select ip,
       avg(case when hour(date) = 00 then temp end) as temp_00,
       avg(case when hour(date) = 01 then temp end) as temp_01,
       avg(case when hour(date) = 02 then temp end) as temp_02,
       . . .
from t
where date >= '2017-03-20' and
      date < '2017-03-21'
group by ip;
```

Comment: too fast. Speedy Gordonzales :)

Comment: Thanks a lot you sql wizard, it works like a charm ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `View`.
Some help:
[Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)
[W3Resource](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-views.php)